# NDFA has maximum states as 2^n the same for qubits in quantum computation.How they can be distinguished in means of computation?

Tags: finite-automata, quantum-computing

I am a Computer Engineer. I studied basics of Quantum Computation. In dealing with multiple states, I feel NDFA does similar to Quantum Computation but we preferred to convert NDFA to DFA and solved problems. But in era of Quantum we prefer this multiple state quantum property to deal with major NP problems. Why? Where they both looks similar and where they differ in terms of Computation

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Also, NDFAs and Quantum machines are very, very different. Nondeterminism is not the same as quantum computation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks I got some sort of clearance from the above mentioned QA. But has to go a long to get clarity on QTM functionality.  thanks once again.

Comment: @Shaull Yeah I got confusion around that non determinism concept used in both on quantum level and NDFA. Thanks.